# How to build this JSON in javascript using this JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON, how do I iterate through this JSON Object in order to get a JSON like the one below this example?

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-06-17",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-06-17": {
            "1. open": "355.1500",
            "2. high": "355.4000",
            "3. low": "351.0900",
            "4. close": "351.5900",
            "5. volume": "28429011"
        },
        "2020-06-16": {
            "1. open": "351.4600",
            "2. high": "353.2000",
            "3. low": "344.7200",
            "4. close": "352.0800",
            "5. volume": "41357182"
        },
        "2020-06-15": {
            "1. open": "333.2500",
            "2. high": "345.6800",
            "3. low": "332.5800",
            "4. close": "342.9900",
            "5. volume": "34702230"
        },
```

**Desired JSON**

```
{"close":69.06,"date":"20161020","high":70.1,"low":68.51,"open":68.87,"openInt":0,"volume":736533}
```

How do I append on each list the value

```
"openInt":0
```

and get the date of each element while appending it to the new desired JSON?

```
"2020-06-15":
```

Currently I'm able to build the JSON with this code

```
const timeSeries = json['Time Series (1min)'];
var data = [];
Object.keys(timeSeries).forEach(key => {
   const d = timeSeries[key];
   d.date = new Date(key);
   data.push( d );
});
```

And it returns a list of jsons like this

```
{"close":69.06,"high":70.1,"low":68.51,"open":68.87,"volume":736533}
```

I know that to get the format date I would use

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d"); // 20150630
```

Comment: You can use `d.date = key.replace('-', '')`

Comment: That do return ```date: "202006-17"``` parsing the date is not the issue, I'm trying to append that date data to the var[data]